# Unnecessary cast checking

Tags: c++, visual-studio

In visual studio if you have Max warning level you will receive warnings about downcasting variables. Such as:

```
warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'x' to 'y', possible loss of data
```

I have currently changed some data types in a fairly large set of code. It is now compiling successfully. The problem is that I am assuming in the code base there is a large amount of casts that are no longer necessary.

In short is there anyway to get Visual Studio to report unnecessary casts? such as:

```
long foo = 10;
long bar = static_cast<long>(foo);
```

Perhaps something along the lines of.

```
Cast from type long to long is unnecessary. They are already the same type.
```

Comment: You don't have to worry about these casts. Your compiler is smart enough to know what to do !

Comment: It is more for creating clean and clear code then a optimization standpoint.

Comment: Sorry but I am not aware of anything like that. It's up to the developer to prevent such things.

Comment: Well, it's good you want to clean up the clutter still left. Though there's a problem: Sometimes, the types are the same, but they aren't. There is the difference between the semantic type and the actual type, and what corresponds in one implementation need not correspond in another. To a limited extent, a tool might be able to understand that...

Comment: GCC has -Wuseless-cast

Comment: In a good program, cast are only used for a good reason. Best avoid them by using the appropriate type, i.e. via `auto`. In your code snippet, for example, the cast should never have been made.